# include media player classic in my .net application

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, media-player, vb.net-2010

In one of my .net project I have to play almost all video files ( flv, mp4 etc ) inside my .net application. So that other than windows media player, I have to include Windows Media player classic in my application. Is it possible ? I am very new to .net.

Please help
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, no. But apparently VLC is comparable to MPC-HC as far as supported media goes, and it has an API you can use to embed it in your app. There are even .Net wrappers for it, I believe.

(I realize this is old... just posting this for others who come here.)

Answer (score 0):

I think it can help you [Embedding the Windows Media Player Control in a C# Solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/dd562851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).